# Excel: Building dynamic range for use in Correl-Function

Tags: excel, dynamic, range, correlation

Good morning from Germany,

I want to do a 30/90 days correlation analysis of two data sets using the Correl-function in Microsoft Excel, but I am currently struggling to get it two work.

The Correl-function in Microsoft Excel needs two data ranges as input:
=Correl(range1,range2)

Range1 and Range2 are data tables of similar size and structure, consisting of one date column and one value column. Every day, a new data set (date and value) is added to each tabel.

I manage to finde the last entry and the entry 30/90 days ago through this function:
=INDEX(fCorrelations!K:K,COUNTA(fCorrelations!G:G))
=INDEX(fCorrelations!K:K,COUNTA(fCorrelations!G:G)-Date!H1)

Those functions return the values I am looking for, but for my purpose I need to get the "address" of the cells consisting the values.

I have tried implementing the functions above into the Correl-function, but I get an error.
=CORREL(INDEX(fCorrelations!K:K,COUNTA(fCorrelations!G:G)),INDEX(fCorrelations!K:K,COUNTA(fCorrelations!G:G)-Date!H1))

Can anybody help, how do get the ranges dynamically ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The OFFSET() function is your friend here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you go a bit more into detail ? How can I derive the address of the cells with the OFFSET() function ?

Comment: The OFFSET function allows you to specify ranges dynamically. Here is the description, from which you can determine if it serves your purpose: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66